# WIFI conflict with Bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on HP 250 G8. My WiFi practically does not work when Bluetooth enable. I think I have already tried all the possible options that I could google. Could you help me, please?
p.s. I am new in Linux, could you suggest to me what inputs I need to send you for help?

```
    nikshein@nikshein-HP:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:884d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, rtl8821ce
10000:e0:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0d3] (rev 20)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6f1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03f0:6141 HP, Inc HP 280 Silent Wireless Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00e Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:0256 Apple, Inc. 2.4G Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


nikshein@nikshein-HP:~$ lsmod | grep 8821
rtl8821ce            2056192  0
cfg80211              974848  3 rtl8821ce,mt7601u,mac80211

nikshein@nikshein-HP:~$ nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID         MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
*       XXXX  HUAWEI-37FA  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2 


nikshein@nikshein-HP:~$ ls /etc/modprobe.d
alsa-base.conf                  blacklist.conf              blacklist-modem.conf         dkms.conf                       iwlwifi-opt.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist-firewire.conf     blacklist-oss.conf           intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          blacklist-framebuffer.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf  iwlwifi.conf

nikshein@nikshein-HP:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf | tail -n5
# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Comment: I am afraid nothing useful can be done with this device.

Comment: How and why is mt7601u loaded? You have no Mediatek device. Please also add: `nmcli device wifi list` but redact the MAC addresses with XXXX.

Comment: I use rtw_8821ce, no rtl8821ce. Bluetooth and Wifi are working. Kernel 5.17. Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.

Comment: @chili555 I don't know :( Maybe I accidentally added it somehow

Comment: Is there no 5 gHz segment available on your router? Please try setting a fixed channel 11 in the router and see if there is any improvement. Let's also see: `ls /etc/modprobe.d` and: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf | tail -n5`

Comment: @chili555 I have a mobile router and I guess it has only 7 channels, I tried to select channel 7, but it not helped
Also edit my question

Comment: I think @Mahler is probably correct. Please do: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ce` and: `sudo modprobe -r mt7601u` and next: `sudo modprobe rtw_8821ce` Is there any improvement? If so, we'll write a file to make it persistent.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do `sudo modprobe rtw_8821ce` I get:
`nikshein@nikshein-HP:~$ sudo modprobe rtw_8821ce
[sudo] password for nikshein: 
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw_8821ce not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic`

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce` instead. Also, I suggest channel 6 instead of channel 7.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/382042/why-use-wifi-channels-other-than-1-6-or-11

Comment: I have done commands and changed the channel on 6 in my router and I think it helped

Comment: @chili555 or not, it worked but again speed slow

Comment: when Bluetooth is off wifi works well, but if I enable Bluetooth speed of internet down up

Comment: I regret that I have no other useful suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: @chili555 Doesn't matter, Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @chili555 It is about Bt-WiFi coexistence on 2.4 GHz. With realtek devices there is no good solution for Linux yet. It can be solved by either using 5 GHz Wi-Fi, or replacing the wireless device to something else.

Comment: @Pilot6 Correct. I had hoped that the native driver and a fixed channel 6 and the removal of the mt7601u driver might help. No such luck. It's a slow night so I decided to go the extra kilometer to try to help.

Comment: The "obvious" conclusion here is that WiFi and Bluetooth has interference (at least on the 2.4GHz band). So; One more thing to try; get a BT dongle and an extension cable - then try using the BT dongle while placing it "away" from the PC *(disable the internal BT; disble iif possible) *

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks a lot. Just confirming that I had issue of Bluetooth and Wi-Fi interfering after using the 2.4 GHz channel on my router. The weird Wi-Fi instability was resolved after switching back the Wi-Fi to use the 5 GHz band. (my setup for reference: Ubuntu 22.04.3, kernel 6.2.0, lsmod shows rtw88_8821ce, motherboard Gigabyte B650M gaming WiFi rev 1.0)